# Why does Python add extra quotes in my array returned by split()?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Here is the relevant data being parsed:

```
alternateClassName: 'FutureSurvey',
alternateClassName: ['HardwareSurvey'],
alternateClassName: ['OptimismSurvey', 'OptimismSurveyTwo']
```

Here is my regex:

```
alternate_regex = re.compile('.*?alternateClassName\s*:\s*(\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]|[\'\"]\s*(.*?)\s*[\'\"]).*', re.M)
```

And here is my code:

```
alternate_match = alternate_regex.match(line)
if alternate_match and alternate_match.group and alternate_match.group(1):
    alternateList = alternate_match.group(1).strip().split(',')
    print alternateList
    dependent_mapping[classpathTxt]['alternateList'] = alternateList
```

Here is what gets printed:

```
["'FutureSurvey'"]
["['HardwareSurvey']"]
["['OptimismSurvey',", "'OptimismSurveyTwo']"]
```

I would have expected this:

```
['FutureSurvey']
['HardwareSurvey']
['OptimismSurvey', 'OptimismSurveyTwo']
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: It's not adding extra quotes. It's reading in the single quotes from the file as regular characters and displaying that string (single quotes included) within double quotes, as usual. If you want to get rid of the single quotes you need to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Your [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) isn't doing anything, because it doesn't have a parameter. Instead, replace it with `.strip("'")`

```
>>> x = "'hello'"
>>> x.strip()
"'hello'"
>>> x.strip("'")
'hello'
>>>
```

Comment: This seems to do just what I want: alternateList = alternate_match.group(1).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", '').replace(" ", '').split(',')